# C# Getting most popular combination of 2 items in collection

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a collection of items, here it is:

```
    ID    ELECT1        ELECT2
    1      FDI           AED     
    2      BPG           AED
    3      AED           FDI
    4      FDI           AED 
    5      GPH           AED
    6      AED           BPG
    7      GPH           FDI
```

And I would like to group elect1 and elect2 and than output the 2 most popular so like
These items are chosen 3 times

```
FDI AED 
AED FDI
FDI AED
```

And then the second most popular combination is

```
AED BPG
BPG AED
```

So the output would be

```
2 Most popular combinations are
    FDI AED 
    AED BPG
```

I have written some code but I don't know how I could possibly do this

```
var groups = cStudent.GroupBy(x => new { x.elective1, x.elective2 });    
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1}:", group.Key.elective1, group.Key.elective2);
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0} ({1})", item.elective1, item.elective2);
    }
}
```

So this is what I get with my code it is halfway there just don't know how to finish.
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHOcn.png)

Comment: Aren't items 1 and 4 the same?

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, the cleanest way to solve this is implementing a custom equality comparer that provides the needed equality semantics to solve your current problem:

```
class IgnoreElectiveOrderStudentEqualityComparer 
    : IEqualityComparer<Student>
{
    public bool Equals(Student x, Student y)
        => (x.ElectiveOne == y.ElectiveOne &&
            x.ElectiveTwo == y.ElectiveTwo) ||
           (x.ElectiveOne == y.ElectiveTwo &&
            x.ElectiveTwo == y.ElectiveOne);

    public int GetHashCode(Student obj)
        => obj.ElectiveOne.GetHashCode() ^
           obj.ElectiveTwo.GetHashCode();
}
```

And now you simply use `GroupBy` and the custom comparer:

```
var mostPopular = 
    students.GroupBy(s => s,
                     new IgnoreElectiveOrderStudentEqualityComparer())
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .Select(g => new
            {
                g.Key.ElectiveOne, 
                g.Key.ElectiveTwo
            })
            .Take(2);
```

Comment: You're right -- I miss read your code, of course XOR is an order independent operator.  (I saw concatenation for some reason.)

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to have the order of the two electives of not matter so the alpha first one is always first (thus if you have (math, art) it is the same as (art, math):

```
var most_pop = cStudent.GroupBy(x => { if (string.Compare(x.elective1,x.elecitive2) > 0) 
                                         return(new Tuple(x.elective1.x.elective2);
                                       else
                                         return(new Tuple(x.elective2,x.elective1);
                                     },
                                (b, a) => new {  Key = b, Count = a.Count() })
                .OrderyByDesending(x => x.Count).Take(2);
```

You could add a select of the key if you don't want an object with the count.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
cStudent
    .Select(x => new[] { x.elective1, x.elective2 }.OrderBy(y => y).ToArray())
    .GroupBy(x => Tuple.Create(x[0], x[1]), (k, g) => new { Elective = k, Count = g.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
    .Select(x => new { elective1 = x.Elective.Item1, elective2 = x.Elective.Item2 })
    .Take(2)
```